# how to run the eclipse generated openhab binding in raspberry pi

Tags: java, openhab

I have added some new thing to openHAB serial binding,using eclipse ide .Its working correctly.Now I want to Know how can i dumb eclipse code into the Raspberry Pi.
Please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to run a maven build (in or outside) of eclipse.

This is from the openHAB-Wiki (http://docs.openhab.org/developers/development/ide.html)

> Note, that if you wish to produce a distribution binary that you will later copy to a different machine, you will need to build in a different manner. Distribution builds are done with maven. Go into the root directory of the project and run ‘mvn install’

After a succesful maven build, you can find your new built jar in the target-Directory of your Binding. Paste this on the raspberrys openHAB installation.